# Select multiple values and compare them using XQuery or XPath?

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have the following XML:

```
<items>
 <item min="1" max="3"> </item>
 <item min="2" max="7"> </item>
 <item min="1" max="2"> </item>
</items>
```

And I need to check for every item if min is always smaller than max. Expected output for this input would be `false` as `@min="2"` is not smaller than `@max="2"`.

I've tried something similar to:

```
every $min,$max  in //item/@min, //item/@max satisfies ...
```

But that's obviously not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `satisfies`, just invert the condition and use `not(...)`.

This query will return all `@min` attributes that fulfill the condition:

```
//item/@min[not(. >= //item/@max)]
```

If you want to use `satisfies`, use this query:

```
//item/@min[every $max in //item/@max satisfies . < $max]
```

---

If you want to know whether all elements fulfill the condition, check no elements do not fulfill it:

```
not(//item/@min[. >= //item/@max])
```

You could even do without a predicate (XPath/XQuery comparisons have a set-like semantic, this means true iff one `@min` value that is equal or greater than one `@max` value):

```
not(//item/@min >= //item/@max)
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want to obtain what min attributes fulfill the condition. I only want to check if they all fulfill it (I'm testing the response of a web service) so I only need a true/false output.

Comment: All you have to do is pull the `not(...)` out of the predicate. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't expressed your requirements very clearly, but it sounds to be as if you want the highest @min to be less than the lowest @max, which would be

```
max(item/@min) lt min(item/@max)
```